# Moving the '&&' into switch

Tags: c

I'm currently having a problem with my code. What I want is to check for buttons with &&, however it's impossible for me to reference them in the cases.

```
#include "n64.h"
#include "explode.h"

MarioStruct *Mario = (void*)M64_MARIO_STRUCT;

void _start() {
    asm volatile("la $gp, _gp");
    switch(Mario->pad->currentButton && )
    {

    case BUTTON_D_DOWN:
        PrintXY(80, 80, "1, 2, 3");
        break;
    case BUTTON_D_UP:
        PrintXY(80, 80, "Oh Hi");
        break;
    case BUTTON_D_LEFT:
        PrintXY(80, 80, "Lollol");
        break;
    case BUTTON_D_RIGHT:
        PrintXY(80, 80, "Noodle");
        break;
    default:
        PrintXY(80, 80, "Default Msg");
        break;
    }
}
```

So how do I get that switch(Mario->pad->currentButton &&) onto the cases? 
Ex.: how it looks like in If Statements:

```
if(Mario->pad->currentButton && BUTTON_D_DOWN)
```

Comment: Are you sure you need `&&` and not `&`? That `if` statement doesn't seem to make sense with `&&`.

Comment: @interjay, `&&` means and. EG: `if (a == 0 && b == 0)` will return true only if both the statements are true because it means: _do what is in the brackets if a is 0 and b is 0_

Comment: @AshishAhuja Yes, I know what `&&` means. And I stand by my statement above, as OP probably meant to use a bitwise and (`&`).

Comment: @interjay, that's right. Its the bitwise and for boolean logic.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that, since the value for a `case` label must be constant.

If your values are bit-flags which are combined, you can't check for that using a `switch()` since there's no single value to check for.

Also, I think your use of `&&` here is wrong, that's boolean (logic) and, it sounds as if you want `&` which is the bitwise and used for masking.

If it's bits, then a "rake" of `if`:s really is the proper way.

One trick I've used in the (distant!) past is to interpret the bitmask as an index, and use that index to read a jump table of function pointers to go directly to the responsible function. But there's not much reason to do such things these days.

Comment: Curious:  how would this typically be handled?  Something like: make each of those button constants a different bit (only one should be present in `Mario->pad->currentButton`, then `&` with a bitmask that wipes all the other bits, and then switch on that, with the different button constants as cases?

Comment: I've done this lots of times, and the least bad way is to use chains of ifs: `if (x & BUTTON_A) ... if (x & BUTTON_B) ...` etc. I don't know what you're doing here, but in real life it's very rare that you get exactly one button at a time. Another approach (which I haven't used) is that if your architecture has a fast find-lowest-set-bit instruction, you can have a loop which calls that, switches on the result, and continues until it runs out of bits; but it'll be more complex and probably less performant.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems you have: The first is that you use the *logical* operator and not the bitwise. The other is that you can't do that with a `switch` statement.

Also, you need to think about what would happen if two buttons were pressed at the same time. With a `switch` statement you would only be able to handle one of them.